# How can I buy an app from the App Store and download it to my wife's iPad?

Tags: ipad, ios-appstore

How can I buy an app from the App Store and download it to my wife's iPad?

Answer (score 4):

**Gift an item on an iOS device**

1. Find the item in the App store or iTunes store that you wish to gift.
2. Tap the Share icon in the upper right.
3. Tap the Gift icon.
4. Sign in to the iTunes Store with your Apple ID.
5. Type the email address for the person you want to send the iTunes Gift to.
6. If you want to, add a message.
7. Pick the day you want to send the gift.
8. Select a theme for your gift.
9. Tap Buy, then tap Buy to confirm.

**Gift an item on Mac or PC**

1. Sign in to the iTunes Store with your Apple ID.
2. Find the item in the App Store or iTunes Store that you wish to gift.
3. Click the arrow to the right of the price and select Gift This.
4. Type the email address for the person you want to send the iTunes Gift to.
5. If you want to, add a message.
6. Pick the day you want to send the gift and click Next.
7. Select a theme for your gift and click Next.
8. Confirm your gift purchase and click Buy Gift.

Ref: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201783

Comment: unofficially, and untested, maybe finding the purchased app on your mac/pc (.ipa file), plugin your wife's iPad, open up iFunbox, and install the .ipa into your Wife's iPad. (the app purchased is by you, and your wife gets and uses it for free) **THIS HASN'T BEEN TESTED. try at your own risk, because I think it would work, but I don't know**

Comment: @MrU If it were that easy, everybody would be doing it ;)

Comment: Well I don't know if everyone's doing it. eh?

Answer (score 0):

## Family Sharing

Apple offers [*Family Sharing*](https://www.apple.com/family-sharing/) where you can share ownership of the app with your wife. No need for an additional purchase.

See: [*Share App Store, iTunes Store, and Apple Books purchases with Family Sharing*](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201085)